# Problem with the first Initialization of my LN node, dial tcp my-external-ip:9735: connect: connection timed out

Tags: lightning-network, ubuntu, linux, lightning-network-daemon, tcp

**Background**

I was following [402 Payment Required's LN video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0siLF9zmWo) and everything was good until the moment of the first Initialization of my LN node. I got an error: `dial tcp my-external-ip:9735: connect: connection timed out`.

I was starting the Initialization by the following way

```
lnd --externalip=X.X.X.X
```

And I've my lnd configuration file with the following attributes

```
alias=
debuglevel=debug
bitcoin.active=1
bitcoin.mainnet=1
bitcoin.node=bitcoind
```

I created the file (before) I started the Initialization.

**Your environment**

version of lnd: I don't know, I guess it's the latest version.
which operating system (uname -a on *Nix): Ubuntu 18.04
version of btcd, bitcoind, or other backend: bitcoind 0.19.1
any other relevant environment details: My Ubuntu is running on a VM machine
with a (bridged) internet connection

**Steps to reproduce**

I don't know how to reproduce the problem but here is a log with my issue

```
2020-08-14 20:33:16.008 [INF] BTCN: Server listening on [::]:9735
2020-08-14 20:33:16.009 [INF] SRVR: Initializing peer network bootstrappers!
2020-08-14 20:33:16.009 [INF] SRVR: Creating DNS peer bootstrapper with seeds: [[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:33:16.010 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: Authenticated Channel Graph
2020-08-14 20:33:16.022 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: [[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:33:16.426 [INF] DISC: Obtained 1 addrs to bootstrap network with
2020-08-14 20:33:19.428 [DBG] SRVR: Waiting 2s before trying to locate bootstrap peers (attempt #1)
2020-08-14 20:33:21.428 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: [[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:33:21.463 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: Authenticated Channel Graph
2020-08-14 20:33:21.464 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
2020-08-14 20:33:21.464 [DBG] SRVR: Waiting 4s before trying to locate bootstrap peers (attempt #2)
2020-08-14 20:33:25.464 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: [[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:33:25.504 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: Authenticated Channel Graph
2020-08-14 20:33:25.504 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
2020-08-14 20:33:25.504 [DBG] SRVR: Waiting 8s before trying to locate bootstrap peers (attempt #3)
2020-08-14 20:33:33.504 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: 
[[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:33:33.539 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: Authenticated Channel Graph
2020-08-14 20:33:33.539 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
2020-08-14 20:33:33.539 [DBG] SRVR: Waiting 16s before trying to locate bootstrap peers (attempt #4)
2020-08-14 20:33:49.540 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: Authenticated Channel Graph
2020-08-14 20:33:49.540 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: [[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:33:49.578 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
2020-08-14 20:33:49.578 [DBG] SRVR: Waiting 32s before trying to locate bootstrap peers (attempt #5)
2020-08-14 20:34:21.579 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: Authenticated Channel Graph
2020-08-14 20:34:21.580 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: [[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:34:21.735 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
2020-08-14 20:34:21.735 [DBG] SRVR: Waiting 1m0s before trying to locate bootstrap peers (attempt #6)
2020-08-14 20:35:21.736 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: Authenticated Channel Graph
2020-08-14 20:35:21.736 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: [[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:35:22.280 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
2020-08-14 20:35:22.280 [DBG] SRVR: Waiting 1m0s before trying to locate bootstrap peers (attempt #7)
2020-08-14 20:35:27.316 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to connect to @my-external-ip:9735: dial tcp my-external-ip:9735: connect: connection timed out
2020-08-14 20:36:22.280 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: 
[[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:36:22.347 [INF] CRTR: Pruning channel graph using block 0000000000000000000f09423cef42338b27f29244a99deed77411cf2e6edb57 (height=643720)
2020-08-14 20:36:22.349 [INF] CRTR: Block 0000000000000000000f09423cef42338b27f29244a99deed77411cf2e6edb57 (height=643720) closed 0 channels
2020-08-14 20:36:22.461 [DBG] NTFN: Filtering 3178 txns for 0 spend requests at height 643720
2020-08-14 20:36:22.523 [INF] NTFN: New block: height=643720, sha=0000000000000000000f09423cef42338b27f29244a99deed77411cf2e6edb57
2020-08-14 20:36:22.523 [DBG] SWPR: New block: height=643720, sha=0000000000000000000f09423cef42338b27f29244a99deed77411cf2e6edb57
2020-08-14 20:36:22.523 [INF] UTXN: Attempting to graduate height=643720: num_kids=0, num_babies=0
2020-08-14 20:36:22.524 [DBG] DISC: New block: height=643720, hash=0000000000000000000f09423cef42338b27f29244a99deed77411cf2e6edb57
2020-08-14 20:36:22.757 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: Authenticated Channel Graph
2020-08-14 20:36:22.758 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
2020-08-14 20:36:22.758 [DBG] SRVR: Waiting 1m0s before trying to locate bootstrap peers (attempt #8)
```

I tried dig nodes.lightning.directory and got the following output

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> nodes.lightning.directory
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48349
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 25, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nodes.lightning.directory. IN A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 93.46.54.4
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 82.1.254.100
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 83.162.151.227
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 163.158.202.112
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 212.47.254.6
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 3.12.163.140
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 178.128.165.102
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 51.83.41.129
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 193.194.163.53
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 35.229.93.213
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 52.38.99.14
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 3.16.193.211
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 73.147.115.80
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 176.122.101.230
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 173.249.48.168
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 18.223.138.245
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 203.118.186.226
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 104.248.111.88
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 46.59.13.35
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 185.228.141.6
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 98.210.161.137
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 86.176.78.2
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 152.32.173.177
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 176.74.136.237
nodes.lightning.directory. 60 IN A 45.77.156.146
;; Query time: 154 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 14 23:13:30 EET 2020
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 454
```

**Expected behavior**

I expected the Initialization would work normally without any issues.

**Actual behavior**

The first Initialization of the LN node didn't happen, stuck in the loop of trying to locate bootstrap peers

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on Lightning but your log suggests it is trying to obtain a list of lightning peers from `lseed.bitcoinstats.com`

```
2020-08-14 20:34:21.580 [INF] DISC: Attempting to bootstrap with: BOLT-0010 DNS Seed: [[nodes.lightning.directory soa.nodes.lightning.directory] [lseed.bitcoinstats.com ]]
2020-08-14 20:34:21.735 [ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
```

I tried this:

```
$ ping -c 10 bitcoinstats.com
PING bitcoinstats.com(2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=8.04 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=7.81 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=8.62 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=8.53 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=8.45 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=8.63 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=7.99 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=8.49 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=9 ttl=57 time=8.31 ms
64 bytes from 2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8636): icmp_seq=10 ttl=57 time=8.82 ms

--- bitcoinstats.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.817/8.373/8.825/0.310 ms
```

So the parent organisation seems to be operational and hasn't completely blocked ICMP.

```
$ ping -c 10 lseed.bitcoinstats.com
ping: lseed.bitcoinstats.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

$ ping -c 10 nodes.lightning.directory
ping: nodes.lightning.directory: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Which suggests there is a DNS resolution problem with the service(s) your lightning node is configured to use for peer discovery. It may be an intermittent problem.

- The problem may be at their end.
- You might need to rebuild using the latest source in order to pick up some other bootstrap peer service which has replaced the one your lnd node is using.
- You might need to manually specify an initial peer, one that is known to be working.

---

References (old but may shed some light on this):

- https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/1434
- https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/1860